# Get Aerospike hyperLogLog(HLL) intersection count of multiple HLL unions

Tags: python, aerospike, hyperloglog

I have 2 or more HLLs that are unioned, I want to get the intersection count of that unions.
I have used the example from here [hll-python example](https://github.com/aerospike-examples/hll-python/blob/master/hll.py)
Following is my code

```
ops = [hll_ops.hll_get_union(HLL_BIN, records)]
_, _, result1 = client.operate(getKey(value), ops)

ops = [hll_ops.hll_get_union(HLL_BIN, records2)]
_, _, result2 = client.operate(getKey(value2), ops)

ops = [hll_ops.hll_get_intersect_count(HLL_BIN, [result1[HLL_BIN]] + [result2[HLL_BIN]])]
_, _, resultVal = client.operate(getKey(value), ops)
print(f'intersectAll={resultVal}')
_, _, resultVal2 = client.operate(getKey(value2), ops)
print(f'intersectAll={resultVal2}')
```

I get 2 different results when I use different keys for the intersection using `hll_get_intersect_count`, i.e resultVal and resultVal2 are not same. This does not happen in the case of union count using function `hll_get_union_count`. Ideally the value of intersection should be the same.
Can any one tell me why is this happening and what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Seems there is some feedback on this thread: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/get-aerospike-hyperloglog-hll-intersection-count-of-multiple-hll-unions/10015/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to figure out the solutions (with the help of Aerospike support, the same question was posted here and discussed more elaboratively [aerospike forum](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/get-aerospike-hyperloglog-hll-intersection-count-of-multiple-hll-unions/10015)).
Posting my code for others having the same issue.

Intersection of HLLs is not supported in Aerospike. However, If I am to get intersection of multiple HLLs I will have to save one union into aerospike and then get intersection count of one vs the rest of the union.
The key we provide in `client.operate` function for `hll_get_intersect_count` is used to get the intersection with the union.
Following is the code I came up with

```
ops = [hll_ops.hll_get_union(HLL_BIN, records)]
_, _, result1 = client.operate(getKey(value), ops)

# init HLL bucket
ops = [hll_ops.hll_init(HLL_BIN, NUM_INDEX_BITS, NUM_MH_BITS)]
_, _, _ = client.operate(getKey('dummy'), ops)
# get set union and insert to inited hll bucket and save it for 5 mins(300 sec)
# use hll_set_union to save the HLL into aeropike temporarily
ops = [hll_ops.hll_set_union(HLL_BIN, [records2])]
_, _, _ = client.operate(getKey('dummy'), ops, meta={"ttl": 300})

ops = [hll_ops.hll_get_intersect_count(HLL_BIN, [result1[HLL_BIN]])]
_, _, resultVal = client.operate(getKey('dummy'), ops)
print(f'intersectAll={resultVal}')
```

For more reference, you can look here for hll_set_union
[reference](https://github.com/aerospike-examples/hll-python/blob/master/hll.py).
More elaborate discussion can be found here

Comment: Thank  you for posting the cross reference to the Aerospike discussion forum where this issue got discussed in further detail.  I also realized the documentation could be improved, I submitted changes.